# Minimal coordination usage

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The constitution provides a set of basic rules that allow for **minimal coordination** amongst members of a society.

What does minimal coordination here mean? I infer that Constitution confers provisions for the **least** (as little as possible) coordination amongst citizens. But I think it's supposed to mean **bare minimum**. However, the word allow preceding it doesn't seem apt to take the meaning of the phrase as bare minimum? Am I missing something, or is this a poorly structured sentence?

Comment: You read it right, though whether it means “very little” or “the least possible” is ambiguous, and IMO, doesn’t really matter. “Allow” is used because the low need for coordination is seen as a benefit or feature. If I had a magic flying pill I could say “taking this pill will *allow* you to fly”, because being able to fly is a good thing, and you can’t do it right now, and I’m emphasizing those two points simultaneously.

Comment: @DanBron The context of this sentence is to state one of the principal goals of Constitution. So it's quite relevant, at least in this sentence, what is implied. As such, Constitution is supposed to expressly allow for as much coordination as possible, I reckon.

Comment: I may be missing you, but the bottom line is the sentence, in English, without taking into account legislative or juridical interpretations which may have already taken place in your country (which take present over superficial or barefaced English readings) is *the basic rules permit citizens to go about their daily lives and interactions without having to do a lot of ad-hoc or local coordination*. Basically “these are the rules of the game, so they don’t need to be constantly renegotiated or relitigated in every local context or every citizen-to-citizen interaction”.

Comment: @DanBron ahh. You've just given me a wider interpretation. But I think I failed at articulating my problem. Consider the sentence - a teacher facilitates minimal coordination amongst the students of the class. Would it imply the teacher doesn't want to promote extensive coordination (beyond what the teacher is allowing)? Or would it just imply that teacher facilitates the requisite level of coordination (without necessarily not wanting more of coordination)?

Comment: I could answer that question, but to do so is dangerous because I think the analogy inapt. Facilitation is different than permission (or, if you prefer, empowerment), at a minimum because the former is *active*. The sentence has the meaning I outlined in my previous comment; it doesn’t speak to (for or against or otherwise), as far as I read, any aspirations beyond that meaning. Maybe the Constitution wants to allow more than the bare minimum; maybe it doesn’t. But it *doesn’t say* either way.

Comment: Btw, in an earlier comment autocorrect changed my intended phrasing “take precedent” to “take present”.

Comment: How could any of that affect anything about English or any other language, please? Which constitution are you asking about? If you think any society has a constitution that provides basic rules for minimal coordination amongst members then please, post that part of that particular constitution…

Otherwise where on Earth did you get the idea… might it have been England in particular or later, Britain in general? France? Russia? US America? Ruritania?

Where did your “bare minimum” come from and where could it possibly lead, please?